# missing FROM-clause entry for table - PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

When I try to run the following code, I get this error: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "photos_cateogry"`

```
photos = Photo.objects.all().extra(
    select={
        'sort_count':
            """
            (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM comments_comment WHERE comments_comment.photo_id=photos_cateogry.id) +
            (SELECT COUNT('likers') FROM photos_category WHERE photos_category.photo_id=photos_category.id)
            """
    }
)
```

Would anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: You spelled `photos_category` wrong at the end of the first select.

Comment: @DanLowe Good catch - thank you! However, I am still getting that error.

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing the right id when joining? This part seems weird to me: `... WHERE photos_category.photo_id=photos_category.id`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `photos_category` table in the `FROM` clause

```
   photos = Photo.objects.all().extra(
        select={
            'sort_count':
                """
                (SELECT COUNT('id') FROM comments_comment,photos_category WHERE comments_comment.photo_id=photos_category.id) +
                (SELECT COUNT('likers') FROM photos_category WHERE photos_category.photo_id=photos_category.id)
                """
        }
    )
```